# How to pass retrieved json data to a function?

Tags: json, angular, ionic2

I want to pass the item.translatedText to the read function.

Here's front end page.

```
  <ion-card *ngFor="let item of items" >
    <ion-card-content>
      {{item.translatedText}}
      <ion-row>
      </ion-row>
      <button ion-button clear small icon-left color="primary" (click)="read()">
  <ion-icon name="musical-notes"></ion-icon>
```

Here's back end page.

```
async read() : Promise<any> {
  //Read the text from the model via TTS
  try {
    await this.tts.speak(this.translatedText);
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens to your front end component / service code?

Comment: why not pass the `item.translatedText` as a parameter in your `read` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you can simply pass that value into the read function directly. Here's how you could do that:

Template:

```
  <ion-card *ngFor="let item of items" >
    <ion-card-content>
      {{item.translatedText}}
      <ion-row>
      </ion-row>
      <button ion-button clear small icon-left color="primary" (click)="read(item.translatedText)">
  <ion-icon name="musical-notes"></ion-icon>
```

And then an update to the read method to accept the translated text as a parameter:

```
async read(translatedText) : Promise<any> {
  //Read the text from the model via TTS
  try {
    await this.tts.speak(translatedText);
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Since it was successful, can you accept this answer?